# SHAP value can explain right?

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost, data-science-model, ensemble-modeling

I face a problem with using SHAP value to interpret the Tree-based model.
(https://github.com/slundberg/shapsd)
First, I have input around 30 features and I have 2 features that have high positive correlation between them.
After that, I train the XGBoost model(python) and look at SHAP values of 2 features the SHAP values have negative correlation.

Could you all explain to me, why the output SHAP values between 2 features don't have the correlation the same as input correlation? and I can trust that output of SHAP or not?

## =========================

The correlation between input: 0.91788
The correlation between SHAP values: -0.661088

2 features are
1) Pupulation in province and
2) Number of family in province.

Model Performance
Train AUC: 0.73
Test AUC: 0.71

Scatter plot
[Input scatter plot (x: Number of family in province, y: Pupulation in province)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3QOS.png)
[SHAP values output scatter plot (x: Number of family in province, y: Pupulation in province)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgd3M.png)

Comment: can you add why this is not what you expected? maybe your target is related to the number of singles in a province or something similar :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you meant by correlation between SHAP values is "SHAP Interaction Value".

SHAP value is a measure how feature values are contributing a target variable in observation level. **Likewise SHAP interaction value considers target values** while correlation between features (Pearson, Spearman etc) does not involve target values therefore they might have different magnitudes and directions.

**The features may grow together but their contribution to target variable in different intervals may reverse.**

You may want to check [docs](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/README.md) and this beautiful [work](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that, despite Shapley values being designed to take correlation into account, SHAP is only an approximation of it. Reading https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7062-a-unified-approach-to-interpreting-model-predictions.pdf, notably the first sentence of 4.1, you can note that SHAP assume feature independence. I wouldn't be surprised if the approximation crumble with very high correlations.